# MPU-9250 IMU on SPI, external sensor or magnetometer using I2C master

Tags: i2c, spi, mpu6050, magnetometer

I'm trying (for sport...) to use an MPU-9250 in SPI mode as it should be faster, and wasn't able to talk to the embedded magnetometer [in my code](https://github.com/exmakhina/libimu/commit/27fc4e7bbfda87061ca8e1bfd4b0121ef318199b).

I've gone through the documentation (RM-MPU-9250A-00 v1.4) which is a bit spartan on that subject but gives the rough idea, it should work by enabling the built-in I2C master feature and using "proxy" I2C registers; I've tried to "do as it says" to communicate with the magnetometer; I'm querying the magnetometer identification register, and I only see 0x00 in there.

I searched in nature, and couldn't find an example of F/LOSS software using an external sensor plugged on the MPU.

Perhaps I've done something wrong but I can't see it, so here's a bottle in the ocean :)

Comment: Why would you need to enable I2C master if you want to use SPI?  That just seems wrong, like the author of the doc was having a bad day.  Can you search around and see if there is any other evidence that this is the right thing to do,

Comment: The IMU chip can act as an I2C master to talk to downstream I2C devices...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my mistake was in the SPI communication code, but nevertheless here is some info because it's not very obvious.

I went over the top and:

- Review the electrical interface to see whether by any chance, my chip was badly hooked-up. Everything was fine.
- Enabled register read-back and saw that... owww, it was bad.
- Reviewing *PS-MPU-9250A-01 § 7.5 SPI Interface* I saw that I had made a stupid copy&paste error in my code... when copying my read code over to the write I forgot to adjust the MSB of the first spi byte.

Then:

- I2C_MST_P_NSR=1 seems important or we get zeros
- basic config [in there](https://github.com/exmakhina/libimu/blob/c68e38c897b8604e30da9afb25a6dd070bb98458/imu_mpu9250.i#L346), currently using the I2C proxy to read the magnetometer, and I don't like having a sleep to wait for I2C transfers to happen or not, but this is a WIP and the code won't go anywhere.

Comment: accept your onwn answer